# Using Bash find to recursively check non square jpg image dimensions, im very close

Tags: bash, image, find, dimensions, identify

I am trying to recursively loop through all directories and print a full path list of all jpg files that are not perfectly square.

here is something I was using to find directories between 2 and 6 deep that are missing a cover.jpg:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 6 -type d '!' -exec test -e "{}/cover.jpg" ';' -print
```

I then modified that to try and find the non square images:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 6 -type d '!' -exec identify -format '%[fx:(h == w)]' "{}/cover.jpg" ';'
```

The above is very close to working, it starts outputting 0 and 1 based on the result of being square or not, but the 0 or 1 is output to the same line instead of a new line, and it just continues on the same line as it checks the files.

```
1111111111111111111111111111111001100101101110111001110010101001011000001101
```

I was thinking if it output a single 1 or 0 per line I could grep it if **0** and print the file path.

I don't have a ton of Bash experience, and so far I am having no luck. Appreciate any help.

Comment: `-iname '*.jpg'` if you're searching for files ending in `.jpg` case insensitive.

Comment: Is this the `identify` from imagemagick? If so, just append `\n` to the format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php) documentation, I think you can just append the newline (and path) to the format:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 6 -type d '!' -exec \
    identify -format '%[fx:(h == w)] %d/%f\n' "{}/cover.jpg" ';' |\
sed -n '/^0 / s///p'
```

(Untested code as I don't have imagemagick installed. The `sed` command implements the grep and strips the leading zero that was added.)

Comment: I didn't notice the `!` in the find command. I think it isn't needed here.

Comment: you are correct, I just tested it without the '!' works without it

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to do with a loop.

```sh
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 6 -type d '!' | while read file; do #Piping find results into loop

    identify -format '%[fx:(h == w)]' "$file/cover.jpg" ';' #For each file, it runs the command you gave
    printf "\n" #Prints a new line

done
```